# Running same go program multiple time throws panic: send on closed channel

Tags: go

I am new to golang and trying to understand how workerpool works. Following sample program works fine if i run once and if try to run multiple times i get **panic: send on closed channel** error. Go version is go1.14.2

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)
func main() {
    jobs := make(chan int, 10)
    results := make(chan int, 10)

    for x := 1; x <= 3; x++ {
        go worker(x, jobs, results)
    }

    for j := 1; j <= 6; j++ {
        jobs <- j
    }
    close(jobs)
    for r:=range results{
        fmt.Println("Result received from worker: ", r)
    }
}
func worker(ID int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {
    for job := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("Worker ", ID, " is working on job ", job)
        time.Sleep(1000*time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println("Worker ", ID, " completed work on job ", job)
        results <- job
    }
    close(results)
}
```

First run is ok

```
go run main.go                                                                            
Worker  3  is working on job  1
Worker  1  is working on job  2
Worker  2  is working on job  3
Worker  2  completed work on job  3
Worker  2  is working on job  4
Result received from worker:  3
Worker  1  completed work on job  2
Worker  1  is working on job  5
Result received from worker:  2
Worker  3  completed work on job  1
Worker  3  is working on job  6
Result received from worker:  1
Worker  3  completed work on job  6
Result received from worker:  6
```

Second run gives this.

```
Worker  3  is working on job  2
Worker  2  is working on job  3
Worker  1  is working on job  1
Worker  3  completed work on job  2
Worker  3  is working on job  4
Worker  2  completed work on job  3
Worker  2  is working on job  5
Worker  1  completed work on job  1
Worker  1  is working on job  6
Result received from worker:  2
Result received from worker:  3
Result received from worker:  1
Worker  1  completed work on job  6
Worker  3  completed work on job  4
Result received from worker:  6
panic: send on closed channel

goroutine 35 [running]:
main.worker(0x3, 0xc0000b0000, 0xc0000b00b0)
    /home/jibi_makkar/code/go/src/main.go:30 +0x252
created by main.main
    /home/jibi_makkar/code/go/src/main.go:13 +0xad
exit status 2
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on ?

Comment: *"program works fine if i run once and if try to run multiple times"* That's the nature of race conditions: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Don't be fooled into thinking it's always the *first time* that it works, or anything similar.

Comment: thanks @JonathonReinhart for the valuable input. do you know why it shows `goroutine 35 [running]` while i spawned only 3 of them. Is it just that a random number goscheduler assigns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer by Eli Bendersky describes the problem.  This answer describes the fix. I know you didn't ask for a fix, but I assume that you are interested.  So here it is.

The fix is to wait for the worker goroutines to complete before closing the channel. Use a [sync.WaitGroup](https://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup) to implement the wait.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for x := 1; x <= 3; x++ {
    wg.Add(1)  // increment worker counter
    go func(x int) {
        defer wg.Done() // decrement on return from goroutine
        worker(x, jobs, results)
    }(x)
}

// Close results channel when workers are done.
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(results)
}()
```

Run this GoLANG program on the PlayGround:  https://play.golang.org/p/GM-0Gqx0Gbg

Answer (score 5):

You have multiple goroutines closing the `results` channel.

```
func worker(ID int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {
    for job := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("Worker ", ID, " is working on job ", job)
        time.Sleep(1000*time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println("Worker ", ID, " completed work on job ", job)
        results <- job
    }
    close(results)            <<<<-------- Here
}
```

You run this `worker` function in three different concurrent goroutines. The first reaching the marked line closes the channel, and the others try to send on a closed channel in `results <- job` in the loop.

Comment: `func worker(ID int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {` here in this line ,  is there any difference, if I opt `jobs chan int` instead of `jobs <-chan int` ?

Comment: @Arun: this has nothing to do with the static type of the channel.